# SwiftUI multiple Alerts in one view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 Alerts in 1 view like so (*These alerts do work individually*), But when combining 2 alerts into the 1 view its only showing alert 2.

I have read that you need to have these attached to different view.

So I have attached the 1 alert to the `button` and 1 alert to the containing `VStack`. Still only the second alert is showing. I trying to get both alerts to work.

```
var body: some View {
     ScrollView {
         VStack (alignment: .leading) {
             ...some stuff
             VStack {
                 Button(action: {
                        dosomestuff
                        showingIntrestedAlert.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Press Me")
                    }.alert(isPresented: $showingIntrestedAlert) {
                        Alert(title: Text("alert1"), message: Text("showing alert 1"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                    }
             }
          }
          .alert(isPresented: $fromViewModel.alreadyLikedUser) {
            Alert(title: Text("alert2"), message: Text("alert 2 shown"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58836439/12299030?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67265716/14733292?

Comment: sorry that hasn't worked - there must be a simpler way

Answer (score 0):

you can insert multiple alert messages in the following way.

First of all: Declare your variables for every single alert you like to handle.

```
struct xyz : View 
{
    @State private var myFirstAlert : Bool = false
    @State private var mySecondAlert : Bool = false
 ....
}
```

in your body write your button stuff like this...

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Text("Hello World")
        Spacer()
        ....
        Button {
            guard someThingIsEmpty else{
                myFirstAlert = true
                return
            }
            guard somethingIsWrong else {
                mySecondAlert = true
                return
            }
            //Button stuff
        } label: { ZStack {Text("Bla"),....}} .alert(isPresented: self.$myFirstAlert){
         Alert(title: Text("Something went wrong!"))}
    .alert(isPresented: self.$mySecondAlert){
    Alert(title: Text("That was shitty"), message: Text("Something went totally wrong"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Urghs"), action: {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Custom Alert**

You just need to create a custom alert to show multiple Alerts in a single View.

```swift
struct CustomAlertView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    var onConfirm: () -> Void
    var title : String
    var message : String
    let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isPresented {
                content()
                    .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                        Alert(
                            title: Text(title),
                            message: Text(message),
                            primaryButton: .cancel(Text("Yes"), action: {
                                onConfirm()
                            }),
                            secondaryButton: .default(Text("No"), action: {})
                        )
                    }
            } else {
                content()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[Usage:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/506mo.png)**

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State var alert1 : Bool = false
    @State var alert2 : Bool = false
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Custom Alerts")
            Button(action: {
                alert1 = true
            }) {
                Text("Alert 1")
            }
            Button(action: {
                alert2 = true   
            }) {
                Text("Alert 2")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .overlay(
            CustomAlertView(isPresented: $alert1, onConfirm: {    
            }, title: "Custom Alert 1", message: "This is Alert 1.") {
                Text("")
            }
        )
        .overlay(
        CustomAlertView(isPresented: $alert2, onConfirm: {   
        }, title: "Custom Alert 2", message: "This is Alert 2.") {
            Text("")
          }
        )
    }
}
```