# SwiftUI Multiple alerts for same button

Tags: swiftui

The code below only shows the false alert. Is there a way to make the alert match the IF condition?

```
@State var showTrueAlert = false
@State var showFalseAlert = false

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        let isTrue = Bool.random()
        if isTrue {
            self.showTrueAlert = true
            print("True Alert")
        } else {
            self.showFalseAlert = true
            print("False Alert")
        }
    }) {
        Text("Random Alert")
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $showTrueAlert) {
        Alert(title: Text("True"))
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $showFalseAlert) {
        Alert(title: Text("False"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I have two alerts on one view in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069516/how-can-i-have-two-alerts-on-one-view-in-swiftui)

Comment: Yes. These links are very usefull. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `.alert` only once to a View. Create a State which only handles the current State of the Alert and then two variables which decide if false or true was pressed. (might store that in one variable only aswell)

```
struct ContentView6: View {

    @State var showAlert : Bool  = false
    
    @State var showTrueAlert = false
    @State var showFalseAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            let isTrue = Bool.random()
            if isTrue
            {
                self.showTrueAlert = true
                self.showAlert = true
                print("True Alert")
            } else {
                self.showFalseAlert = true
                self.showAlert = true
                print("False Alert")
            }
        }) {
            
            Text("Random Alert")
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>(
            get: {
                self.showAlert
            },
            set: {
                self.showAlert = $0
                self.showTrueAlert = false
                self.showFalseAlert = false
            })) {
            if (showTrueAlert)
            {
                return Alert(title: Text("True"))
            }
            else
            {
                return Alert(title: Text("False"))
            }
          }
      }
}
```